# Reloading the page creates a new tab

Tags: bug, new-nav

I think I discovered a bug in the new navigation system - have a look:

[image: gif of the reproduction]

If I open a navigation tab with a filter for two or more tags and then reload the page, a new tab gets created.
The tag that was open before was saved and had no unsaved changes to it.
It does not matter, whether it is set to *any* or *all*, neither is it important whether there are unsaved changes or not.

Here is the mandatory freehand circle, displaying what should not happen:

[image: freehand circles, yay]

This does not happen if the search contains only one tag.

I reproduced this on three different machines, all running different browsers:

- Safari 9.1 11601.5.17.1 (MacOS X El Capitan)
- IE11 11.0.9600.18204 (Windows 7)
- FF 46.0.1 (Windows 10)

I also just reproduced this on my Android tablet, running Chrome 50.0.2661.89 (Android 6.0)